# Scala and Java Real-Time System

Tags: java, scala, real-time, rtsj

Just wondering if anybody has run Scala app or web-app on Java Real-Time system?

I assume because scala is bytecode compatible with regular JVM, then it should not take much effort to run it on a Real Time JVM such as Sun Java Real-Time System ?

Edit:
As per [Sun Java Realtime System on VirtualMachine / cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564575/sun-java-realtime-system-on-virtualmachine-cloud), I managed to run Scala's Lift framework using Sun Java Realtime system on SuseLinuxEnterprise Realtime Extension on top of VMWare Workstation 6.5

The web-app will not be behaving as a real-time (as it runs on VMWare), but it's a start.

Comment: [Hot Potato](http://hotpotato.com/), the social networking site, runs on Scala. I just went to a [meetup](http://www.meetup.com/NYC-Tech-Talks/calendar/12754545/) on their architecture. Looks like there is a video stream of the event [here](http://www.livestream.com/nytechtalks).

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about this: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/index.jsp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [this sun.com FAQ entry](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/faq.jsp#5), all J2SE applications are supposedly compatible with the Java RTS. The important part there is where it says that all RTSJ implementations must pass the Java TCK to be considered compatible.

Comment: So that means I have to test Scala's Lift framework against Java TCK. Or have anyone done this I wonder.

Comment: No, the above means that Sun have tested their RTSJ runtime against the normal Java TCK and have certified all of this stuff as compatible. All you have to do is drop your compiled Scala code (together with scala-library.jar, Lift, and whatever else it is that you use) into a J2EE container running under an RTSJ runtime. **Then** you test your app.

Answer (score 3):

Scala runs on JamaicaVM, a clean room implementation of the Java runtime environment with a static compiler and a fully deterministic garbage collector.

Comment: Could you please explain "clean room implementation" in detail?