# Sun Java Realtime System on VirtualMachine / cloud

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, real-time

Just wondering if anybody can run/compile application for Sun Java Realtime system JRE on a VM such as VMWare or on the Cloud such as on Amazon EC2 ?

I know it is not ideal running Realtime java on a virtualized infrastructure, but it makes things easier.

(Otherwise I just have to install SLES SP2 on physical hardware.)

Comment: What is the "Sun Java Realtime system" you are talking about?  Do you mean the JRE?  If so it is the Java RUNTIME Environment ... not realtime.

Comment: No, I meant the JRE for Sun Java Realtime system, http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about [Java RTS](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/index.jsp), then there is little chance that you will get decent realtime behavior on a virtual machine of any kind.  In fact, the webpage says that you need a realtime-capable OS, and it lists:

- Solaris 10 (Update 6, Update 7)
- SUSE Linux Enterprise Real Time 10 Service Pack 2 (SP2) update 6 (2.6.22.19-0.22-rt kernel)
- Red Hat Enterprise MRG 1.1 Errata (2.6.24.7-126.el5rt kernel)

**EDIT**

Java RTS on top of a virtualization platform is problematic.  When run in (for example) a VMware virtual, the Java RTS and its host OS do not have control over physical machine resources, and therefore are not in a position to make the performance guarantees required to implement realtime behavior.  Hypothetically, you might be able to do this if the virtualization platform (including the base OS) was fully realtime capable.  But I've never heard of such a thing ... and I have doubts that it is even possible.

As a corollary, I'd be very surprised to hear that Java RTS works "in the cloud".  It would suffer from the same problems as an in-house virtualization platform, etc, plus the problems you have the internet between you and it.

Comment: Yes the website did say that. I don't know if there is an Amazon AMI running SUSE Linux Enterprise Real Time 10 Service Pack 2 (SP2) update 6 (2.6.22.19-0.22-rt kernel), or is it even possible to run the realtime kernel on a Virtualized environment?

All I want is just a playground in the cloud running real time OS, not performance (at this stage)

Comment: I am installing SuseLinux Enterprise SP2 + Real Time extension now on VMWare 6.5. Hopefully it will be ok. If it doesn't, that mean I have to buy a new box to run SLES.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear if the VMWare approach really works.  Please keep us updated!!!

Comment: I have successfully installed SuseLinux Enterprise SP2 + Real Time extension add-on. I could also compile and run a simple Hello world program using Sun Java Realtime System JDK. My underlying OS is XP 64bits.

Comment: Ah yes, but is it really giving you real-time behavior?  Will it continue to do so when other virtuals on the same box are competing for resources?  That is where I have my doubts!

Comment: Nope, I don't think it will give me real-time behaviour. It's enough for me to start playing with it though :)

Comment: I wonder how can I quickly and easily measure how far it is from real "real-time" behaviour?

Comment: I don't think you can do it quickly and easily.  What I would do would be to find ... or write ... some benchmarks / tests that measure the realtime aspects of the JRTS APIs.  Then run them on the virtual with various levels of load on the base OS and/or in other virtuals.